# Formatting a Date of type String using a Formatter Java

Tags: java, jdbc

Is it possible to do format a date of type String using a date formatter? I want to store my Date and Time in the Event class as Strings so that I don't need to convert the Strings loaded from a MYSQL database (using the types DATE and TIME) back into Date types so they can be stored in new Event objects. MySQL only accepts DATE in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD` and TIME in the format of `HH:MM:SS` but i want these to be formatted differently when i go to print them out in my program.

When i run this code i get an `Cannot format given Object as a Date at java.text.DateFormat.format(Unknown Source)` error. If i try using parse() it won't compile because it only accepts Dates.

Main class

```
public Main() {
   ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
   private SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM:SS");
   private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");

   //Stores current time and date
   Date date;
   Date time;
   String d = "";
   String t = "";           

   d= dateFormat.parse(date);
   t= timeFormat.parse(time);

   events.add(d, t);

   //Print out newly formatted date and time when loaded from mysql
   System.out.println(events.get(0).printDate());
   System.out.println(events.get(0).printTime());
}
```

Events class

```
public class Event {    
   private String date;
   private String time;

   public Event(String d, String t) {
      date = d;
      time = t;
   }

   public String printDate() {
       SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YYYY");
       String newDate = format.format(date);
       return newDate;
   }

   public String printTime() {
       SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
       String newTime = format.format(time);
       return newTime;
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to format a string to date ?

Comment: It is generally better to save dates as millis past epoch using `date.getTime()` as it is time-zone neutral, whereas `String` dates are usually based on an unstated assumed timezone.

Comment: In the main class, it gets the current Date and Time and converts it into a String so it can be stored in the Events arraylist. I want to create a method to return the Date and Time strings in a different format.

Comment: Yes, but you would need to parse the `String` to a `Date` first

Comment: Thanks. so i need to convert the Date/Time Strings in the Events class back to Dates in order to reformat it?

Comment: in brief, it doesn't make sense to store date and time as string in your event class....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Event, you should use Date type for date and time field.

This is a more appropriate representation for date and time value.  And with them, you can use DateFormat to do whatever formatting you want

(It will be even better to use Joda time LocalDate and LocalTime for your date and time, but that's a bit off topic)

Answer (score 1):

You can't format your dates because they are `String` objects and `SimpleDateFormat` needs `Date` objects.
You should consider a different way of storing them (either as `Date` or `Calendar`). See below:

```
public class Event
{    
   private Date date;
   private Date time;

   public Event(String d, String t)
   {
      String[] details = d.split("\\-");

      Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
      c.set(Integer.parseInt(details[0]), Integer.parseInt(details[1]), Integer.parseInt(details[2]));

      date = c.getTime();

      details = t.split(":");
      c.set(Integer.parseInt(details[0]), Integer.parseInt(details[1]), Integer.parseInt(details[2]));

      time = c.getTime();
   }

   public String printDate()
   {
          SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
          String newDate = format.format(date);
          return newDate;
   }
   // rest of you class can stay the way it is
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for the right formatting codes. Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format java.util.Date or java.sql.Date (which is subclass of java.util.Date) using date formatter, eg:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String dateStr = df.format(date);
```

Using jdbc ResultSet `getDate()` method you can obtain java.sql.Date object which you can print in any format using method above

Similar techniques can also be used to parse string in any format into a java.util.Date object

```
Date date = df.parse(dateStr);
```